# When installing Magento 2 on xamp, extracted all the files into htdocs. When I go to localhost/magento I get a fatal error

Tags: magento2.2, installation, php-7

> Fatal error: Declaration of
>   Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager::get($name, ?array $options = NULL)
>   must be compatible with
>   Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager::get($name, $options =
>   Array, $usePeeringServiceManagers = true) in
>   G:\wampfebeighteen\htdocs\pehnava\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\PluginManager.php
>   on line 211

Comment: ,Please check you xampp which php version is providing .